# Apache to NGINX Migration - Mime Magic Alternative

Tags: apache, nginx, mime-types

I'm using `nginx/1.10-3` and `apache2-2.4.25-3` on Debian.

For many reasons i won't go into, I'm looking to switch to NGINX from Apache2.

My CMS has many files that either have no extensions, or have the wrong extension in terms of lining up with `mime.types`.

With Apache2 we rely on mod_mime_magic to override the extension and use the magic bytes to correctly set the content-type. However, I can't seem to find a way to get this on NGINX.

For example, we have images that end in `.img` and some files with no extension at all.

The only solution I can come up with, is to integrate extension rewriting/adding into the platform and change the extensions on upload and go through the existing ones. This will take a lot more time, though.

Is there a "hack" or an alternative to mime magic with NGINX?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a pattern in the file's path that could be used to indicate its type? Like an enclosing folder name or something in its filename. If not, you could probably use a map. But this could become tedious if the files change on a regular basis.